# Convert String with "." to int in python

Tags: python, string, integer

I want to convert a string with a point to a int
to us it in time

```
import time

x = "0.5"
time.sleep(int(x))
```

i tried it with this simple code but i get this error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.5'
```

is there an solutuion to convert the string to int

Comment: What `int` do you expect to get back?

Comment: my bad, i want to use this number as a time.sleep i found out now that i have to convert it to float to use it in time.sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert it to float first and then to int

```
x = "0.5"
print(int(float(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert this string to float and than use floor or ceil funtions for valid int

```
x = float(x)
x = math.floor(x) # or math.ceil() by your choice
x = int(x)
```